# Not able to run application using external IP in GCP

Tags: server, firewall, jupyter

I have set up an ubuntu 18.04 machine with 16 gb memory in GCP.
Have reserved a static address and created a firewall rule where i have allowed TCP port 8888.
IP range i have given 0.0.0.0/32.

Installed jupyter lab and its running fine on port 8888 but when im opening in my browser with external IP address its not opening saying that external took too long to respond.
Am i missing anything here.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide all the IP addresses involved and full details on the firewall rule.

Comment: 0.0.0.0/32 matches the (invalid) IP 0.0.0.0. You probably want to listen to 0.0.0.0/0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here i was facing was because of the change in IP address. The IP address of source machine which i mentioned in the firewall rules was no longer available for me. IP address got changed so just updated the new IP address there in firewall rule and i was able to run the Jupyterlab

Answer (score 0):

In Google Cloud Platform all TCP ports except a few (like 22) are firewalled by default at "**VPC Network**" level.

You have to go to **Firewall** under **VPC Network** on your GCP Console and add a rule to allow "Ingress" access to your machine.

Comment: Yeah like i mentioned i have created a new firewall rule and have opened 8888 also allowed my PCs IP in the source IP so that i can interact with my local machine